# How to upgrade Zolando PostgreSQL operator using Helm?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I've installed Zolando PostgreSQL Operator v1.8.1 in bare-metal K8S using helm,

```
helm repo add postgres-operator-charts https://opensource.zalando.com/postgres-operator/charts/postgres-operator
helm install postgres-operator postgres-operator-charts/postgres-operator --version 1.8.1
```

but I'm not sure how to properly upgrade it to v1.8.2?

There is a documentation but it's too high level for me: https://github.com/zalando/postgres-operator/blob/master/docs/administrator.md#upgrading-the-operator

Could somebody provide step-by-step command line how to upgrade operator using Helm or without Helm?

Answer (score 1):

Hope is not too late, I found myself doing this a couple of months ago as well, all you have to do is to change the docker image as explained in the documentation above, to be more specific, the `deployment` docker image. So I assume you have some basic understanding of helm, it is pretty common to have a custom values.yaml file in which you edit the configuration to fit your needs you just need to specify this file while running the upgrade with the `-f` flag.

```yaml
image:
  registry: registry.opensource.zalan.do
  repository: acid/postgres-operator
  tag: v1.8.2
  pullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
```

and then `helm upgrade <your-release> <path-to-your-chart> -f values.yaml -n <your-ns>`

That should be it. (be sure to double check the breaking changes for changes in the crds)

Comment: I tried updating mine using `helm upgrade postgres-operator charts/postgres-operator/postgres-operator-1.10.1.tgz -f charts/postgres-operator/values.yaml`. and I get a bunch of `Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "";.."  Is there another way to do it in the container like how they have mentioned but there is no detail around it.